# How to execute a mongo query stored as a string in a Java Application?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have stored mongo queries as a string in the database and wants to execute them in a java application. Is there any way, I can achieve this...
DB statement example:-
"db.people.updateMany({ age: { $gt: 25 } }, { $set: { status: "C" } })"

Comment: You can try [MongoDB Java Driver Tutorial - Run Command](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/commands/) _or_ similar method in Spring Data MongoDB `MongoTemplate` class.

Comment: The URL you provided was helpful, but I couldn't figure out how to use it for the example I have provided. Can you please elaborate on this?... Also, can you provide some examples on MongoTemplate use... Thanks...

Comment: You have to build the query's _filter_ and _update_ from the stored command string - for the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) write command using the `runCommand`:.